# How do you find out the number of solutions to $x^a \equiv b \pmod{n}$, $x^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod{27}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $x^a \equiv b \pmod{n}$.
How do you find out how many solutions are there?

Another example:
I was given the question: $x^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod{27}$.

If it were a normal equation such as: $12x \equiv 1 \pmod{27},$ I would’ve just said that it was $\gcd(12,27) = 3$.

But in the case of power and multiplication, how do you find the number of solutions? And is there a way to find these solutions without having to try every number?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

There is a general procedure to these type of problems.

**Observation.** Suppose $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^\times=\langle g\rangle$ is cyclic and $\gcd(a,m)=1$. We want to find the solution to the equation $x^n\equiv a \pmod{m}$.

Write $x=g^y$ and $a=g^b$. Then the equation becomes $g^{ny}\equiv g^b \pmod{m}$. So $ny\equiv b \pmod{\phi(m)}$. Now you can solve for $y$ first (if there's any solution) and then find $x$.

And here's a useful theorem.

**Theorem.** If $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is cyclic and $\gcd(a,m)=1$, then $x^n\equiv a \pmod{m}$ has a solution if and only if $a^{\phi(m)/d}\equiv 1\pmod{m}$ where $d:=\gcd(n,\phi(m))$ and $\phi$ is the Euler's totient function. And if solutions exists, then there are $d$ solutions.

Comment: Very nice suggestions!